How do we know that ancient peoples didn't see their gods and mythologies as simple works of fiction?
Suppose that millennia after our civilization is gone, an archeologist discovers a well-preserved treasure trove of manuscripts that describe epic battles between heroes and villains. There are idols carved of the characters, some of them life-size and large enough to bow down to. They might justifiably conclude that we worshipped these titans as deities.
How do we know that ancient people earnestly believed that their gods were real entities that might smite them if they stepped out of line, and not simply legends told around the campfire for entertainment like superheroes are to us?

There are already two good answers,but I just want to note that beginning a question on H:SE with the word "suppose" invites criticism as a potential hypothetical.  I would avoid doing so in the future.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)  How would people behave if they were participating in fiction? how would they behave if they were confronted with the unknown and unknowable, but potentially appeasable?

Because people spent real money on offerings to their gods, including cattle sacrifices and expensive temple offerings. You would not offer your car up to Captain America, but people did offer captured armor (with a value similar to that of a car today) to the Gods.

In many cases, a very expensive car. Like a Rolls Royce.

They also built temples, often as the most expensive buildings in a city.

They also comdemned some citizens to death for blasphemy, which is a sign of taking religiously (too much?) seriously.

Bret Devereaux makes this point a lot: people in the past believed their own religions.
Here he speaks about the Romans, for whom we have the most evidence:

one benefit of this religion, he [Polybius] says, is that Roman magistrates (read: elite Senators) do not steal from the public treasury even when they are not watched, which would seem to imply that even many very elite Romans believed their own religion

...

Roman leaders vowed temples and sacrifices in duress, and built and gave them in victory. Lavish dedications to the gods from all levels of Roman society confirm the overall picture: the Romans believed their religion.

His deep dive into how ancient polytheism worked might be good material for further reading. Religion was seen not as a collection of morals but practical knowledge that allowed you to appease the gods whose power was plain to see in every aspect of life.

We know that there were people who believed that all tales about gods are a fiction. However, the majority of population took gods seriously, and this was enforced by the states. There is an ample evidence of this. For example, major decisions, including military decisions were made depending on the results of sacrifices. There are plenty of examples of this in historical writings. Also people who offended gods could be prosecuted.

I think this is the simplest answer: if there weren't anyone who believed in the gods, then there wouldn't be people who said they didn't believe in the gods.

You know worshipers sacrificed their children in some religions? Especially first born children were considered more valuable. I know of no culture were parents do not cherish their children.
